# set custom icons for everyone

Tags: windows, windows-xp, icons

I am trying to associate custom icons to files on a fileshare for everyone (Windows). It works great for me and I can see the custom icons but if someone else opens the network folder he can not see the icons.

Is there a way to set the icons for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other users don't see the icon because they cannot access the actual `.ico` file by using the same path as you do. For example, if you use an icon located in `C:\Icons\Porn folder.ico`, that path would be stored in a file named `desktop.ini`. When a network user opens the share, his system looks for the *user's* `C:\Icons\`, not yours.

To get around this, edit `desktop.ini` to contain a path that would work over the network - which means the `.ico` file must also be in a publicly-accessible share. If you kept the icons in a share named "Public stuff" and the computer was named `florianpc`, it would be:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconFile=\\florianpc\Public stuff\Icons\Music.ico
```

But this won't work 100% (maybe 98%). It would be even better if you used a path *relative to the folder*. For example, this would make Windows look for a `folder.ico` directly in the folder itself:

```
IconFile=folder.ico
```

*(By the way, Windows actually does this for `folder.jpg` in thumbnail mode.)*

Similarly, this would make Windows go one level up, then look inside "Icons" directory:

```
IconFile=..\Icons\Music.ico
```

---

The `desktop.ini` file usually has both "Hidden" and "System" bits set, so you won't see it until you disable *"Hide protected operating system files"*.

Alternatively, just open Notepad, click *File -> Open*, browse to the folder, and enter `desktop.ini` as name.